# CSS Statement starting with *

Tags: css

I have downloaded the css file off HTML5Reset to use as a starter set of CSS. Looking through the coding, I find there are statements that start with an *, eg. *vertical-align. I have never met this before. What does it mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a hack.

> Versions 7 and below of Internet Explorer recognize properties which
>   are preceded by non-alphanumeric characters except an underscore or a
>   hyphen (after discarding the prefix). All other browsers ignore such
>   properties as invalid. Therefore, a property that is preceded by an
>   non-alphanumeric character other than an underscore or a hyphen, such
>   as an asterisk, is applied exclusively in Internet Explorer 7 and
>   below.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_hack

Comment: +1 for the reference, there're plenty of information of stuff I used a lot without knowing how they accurately work.

Comment: @Sonu Joshi Thanks very much for your answer. I had Googled a number of phrases to try and discover an answer but nothing valid was forthcoming.